# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i\binom{n}{i}=n2^{n-1}$ using induction.

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I have already derived the formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\i
\end{array}\right)=n2^{n-1}$ directly just by doing some algebraic manipulations to the summand, which is indeed proves the validity of the formula. However, for the sake of a challenge I thought that I might try to prove this using induction, and it has turned into a nightmare! After checking the base cases and establishing the hypothesis $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i
\end{array}\right)=k2^{k-1}$ for all $k>1$ I get the following:

Step 1:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k+1\\
i
\end{array}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left[\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i
\end{array}\right)\right]$$

Step 2:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i
\end{array}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i
\end{array}\right)+(k+1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
k+1
\end{array}\right)$$
Step 3:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i
\end{array}\right)+(k+1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
k+1
\end{array}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}$$
Step 4: let $i=j+1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
i-1
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(j+1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
j
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}$$

Step 5:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}j\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
j
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
j
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}j\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
j
\end{array}\right)+k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1\\
j
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}$$
Step 6:
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
j
\end{array}\right)-k\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
k
\end{array}\right)\right)+k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1\\
j
\end{array}\right)+k2^{k-1}=2^{k-1}-k+k2^{k-1}+k^{k-1}$$

I can't get what in need $(k+1)2^{k}$ from this, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At step $4$ you got the wrong upper limit on the summation when you shifted the index. I make it:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\binom{k+1}i&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\left(\binom{k}{i-1}+\binom{k}i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\binom{k}{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\binom{k}i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\binom{k}{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^ki\binom{k}i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k(i+1)\binom{k}i+k2^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^ki\binom{k}i+\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}i+k2^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ki\binom{k}i+2^k+k2^{k-1}\\\\
&=k2^{k-1}+2^k+k2^{k-1}\\\\
&=2k2^{k-1}+2^k\\\\
&=k2^k+2^k\\\\
&=(k+1)2^k
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks! I should have saw that. By the way, what code do you use on here to make your equation in a strait line?

Comment: @Jimmy: You’re welcome! If you right-click on any formula and select `Show Math As > TeX Commands`, you’ll get a popup window showing the exact code used. In this case it’s a block headed by `\begin{align*}` and closed by `\end{align*}`; the `&` signs mark the point of alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Just in your first step:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\binom{k+1}{i}=(k+1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\left(\binom{k}{i-1}+\binom{k}{i}\right)=(k+1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\binom{k}{i-1}+k2^{k-1}$$

Now write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\binom{k}{i-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(i-1+1)\binom{k}{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i\binom{k}{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}=(k2^{k-1}-k)+(2^k-1)$$
finally add all the terms and you get your result

Comment: + for starting will make your day great. امین